Get the position of the agent presentation in the owner agent layout
I need to get the x and y coordinates of the presentation object of a specific agent that lives inside another agent.
See the example below.
The rectangle is inside the object called page. And after placing the agent 'Page' on the main agent I moved the presentation object that was created to a new location.

I now need to be able to find the correct location of where the presentation object was moved to so that I can use it in the code.
I tried using
page.getX();
page.presentation.getX();

But both just return zero
Is there a way to get hold of the presentation object of an agent by only having access to the agent reference?

You could try page_presentation.getX(), but I have replicated your example, and page.getX() also returns the X coordinate of the presentation for me, maybe there is another underlying issue...

Thank you for the contribution. The problem is I the code that wants to manipulate the agent 'page' is found inside the agent and does not know what the user might name the agent as, e.g. 'setup_page' and then the code needs to do something relative to where the user placed the animation of 'setup_page'.

When you place an agent in another one's markup space, its animation gets attached to origin by default. It's important to set "at the agent animation location" option as initial location of page agent (see it's properties). If the specified offset (130; 110) above is a rectangle offset inside page agent exactly, do not forget to additionally take into account this rectangle position there:
page.getX()+page.rectangle.getX()
If you desire to get location of rectangle on main agent from inside Page agent, you need to use the construction like below, i.e. take into account both page agent location and relative rectangle location inside page agent:
getX() + rectangle.getX()

Thank you; this answered my question. However, I realized that my problem is probably in the fact that I set my page agent to "Flow chart block within library" in the advanced section. Could you possibly update the answer to include how to handle this as well? Otherwise, if I don't manage, I will ask a new question that includes this subtle but important difference.
